# I need to call chat sdk from wso2 class mediator

Tags: java, wso2, mediator, chatsdk, wso2-esb

I have compiled chat sdk in android studio ,it is working fine but I need to add it to my app as an extension so how could I call chat sdk into wso2 .

Answer (score 0):

You can call your sdk from the class mediator and do the implementation when your going to deploy the mediator on wso2 you need to copy the sdk jar along with the mediator jar to WSO2_HOME/repository/components/lib

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Actually I am very new to wso2 can you please elaborate your answer

Answer (score -2):

To call a compiled Chat SDK in an Android app, there are a few steps:

Add the SDK as a Gradle dependency in your app's build.gradle file. For example:

```
implementation 'chat.sdk:firebase-app:[latest-version]'
```

Make sure your app inherits from the Chat SDK theme in your styles.xml file:

In your Android app, call the methods and classes from the Chat SDK.The exact implementation will depend on the SDK and your app's
requirements.

When deploying to WSO2, copy the Chat SDK jar file along with your app's jar file to the WSO2_HOME/repository/components/lib folder.

To call the Chat SDK from a WSO2 class mediator, implement the logic in the mediator class and call the Chat SDK classes and methods from within that class.

You may need to install additional libraries to resolve dependencies issues, as mentioned in one of the Stack Overflow answers.

That's the basic process to add a compiled Chat SDK to your Android app and call it from within WSO2. The GitBook documentation provides more details on adding the Chat SDK to a project.